# How to get id and input data when onChange event is happening React js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, onchange

I am new to React js.I am little bit confused that how get id and onChange evt value at the same time when all the data inside map function.Yes there are already answers out there but nothing worked for me.Any method or help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

class Upload extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.handleChangeSinglePost = this.handleChangeSinglePost.bind(this)
        this.handleID = this.handleID.bind(this)
    }
    handleChangeSinglePost(data){
        console.log(data)//Get the input//Not working

    }
    handleID(e){

        console.log(e.target.value)get the Id
    }
    renderMaptheSingleUpload(){
        return(
            this.props.photos.photos.map((data) => {
                return(
                    <div key={data.id} className="WholeWrapperForSingleUpload">
                        <div className="imageContainerUpload">
                            <img src={data.blobData} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="ImageTitleForUpload">
                            <form onChange={this.handleID}>
                                <input onChange={this.handleChangeSinglePost(data.id)}  name="caption" type="text" placeholder="Caption This" />
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            })
        )
    }
    render(){
        // console.log(this.props.photos)
        return(
            <div className="UploaContainer">
                <div className="UploadContainerContents">

                    {this.renderMaptheSingleUpload()}

                    <div className="tagsForupload">
                        <ul>
                            <li>OrdinaryLife</li>
                            <li>OrdinaryLife</li>
                            <li>OrdinaryLife</li>
                            <li>OrdinaryLife</li>
                            <li>OrdinaryLife</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div className="TagItForUpload">
                        <form>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Tag it" />
                            <input type="submit" defaultValue="Post " />
                        </form>
                        <div className="suggestionSystemForTagging">
                            <ul>
                                <li>Drake</li>
                                <li>LetMeChoose</li>
                                <li>LetMeChoose</li>
                                <li>LetMeChoose</li>
                                <li>LetMeChoose</li>
                                <li>LetMeChoose</li>
                                <li>LetMeChoose</li>
                                <li>LetMeChoose</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        photos:state.photoUpload
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Upload)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can use function in onChange event as :

```
<input onChange={e=>this.handleChangeSinglePost(e.target.value, data.id)} " />

 handleChangeSinglePost(value, id){
     console.log("value>>>",value);
     console.log("id>>>",id);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use bind  `handleChangeSinglePost()` to the data like

```
<input onChange={this.handleChangeSinglePost.bind(this,data.id)}  name="caption" type="text" placeholder="Caption This" />
```

Comment: then how should the `handleChangeSinglePost` function should be written

Answer (score 1):

The question is answered but you can also do it using bind.

```
<input onChange={this.handleChangeSinglePost.bind(this, data.id)} type="text"/>
```

And then `handleChangeSinglePost` should looks as follows :

```
handleChangeSinglePost(id, event){
   ......
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1516/).

Answer (score 1):

How about using Closures

```
 handleChangeSinglePost = (id) => (e) => {
    console.log("value>>>",e.target.value);
    console.log("id>>>",id);
 }

 <input onChange={this.handleChangeSinglePost(data.id)} " />
```

If you prefer not to use experimental syntax

```
 handleChangeSinglePost(id) {
  return (e) => {
     console.log("value>>>",e.target.value);
     console.log("id>>>",id);
   }
 }
```

Comment: This will not work as expected if the binding is happening inside a array map. then the id will always be the last data.id in the array